# Facebook Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

Hello everyone
I have a web page.I am sharing my web page on facebook.The page has got a javascript function for resize by window.Here is code of function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeWindow()
   {
      resizeTo(739,582);
      window.resizeTo(739,582);
      top.resizeTo(739,582);
      moveto(739,582);
      window.moveto(739,582);
    }        
</script>
```

When the user click by my url from facebook redirecting to my website but browser doesn't resize by itself.When i close facebook tab and refresh my web page it works.I don't know why i am getting that problem.Anybody has got an idea?
Thanks

Comment: On what event did you bind your resizeWindow function ? ready, load ?

Comment: i hate webmasters which unasked resize my browser window :-)

Comment: Did you try with document ready ? Does it change anything ?

Comment: How did you bind?  <body onLoad=""> or <script>window.onload</script>?  Post your code that binds the onload to function resizeWindow